# Is it possible to keep track of original path of a moved image/folder in PHP Codeigniter without database?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, restore

I am trying to create a file manager or image storage app using php based framework codeigniter in which I want to create a feature to delete and restore images and folders.

So far i have developed every part of the app from upload to delete without the use of database but I could not find any way to restore back the images and folders to their original path.

I'm using PHP's `rename()` function to move the file to the deleted folder before deleting this permanently.

So is it possible to pass the original path info with the image or folder using metadata etc.?

Comment: if you want to implement any features that require "remembering" you need a database or some sort of local storage method. The later would be something like a manifest file stored in json or a serialized format to accompany the image or images that stores the info you want. Hardly a good method (not efficient), and I can see it getting unwieldy rather quickly. Also in the future please note this type of question is too broad.

Comment: I don't know of any OS path information in the meta data. At least that is not a default feature in any OS. So no, I don't think so.

Comment: No, however, if you store a text file with pointers to where the folders have been that would work. Windows has to do the same thing with the registry.

Comment: @CHunter Thanks but what would you recommend text file or database?

Comment: @MuhammadTarique It all depends on what this file manager is for. Is it just for you or is it for multiple people? If it's just for you a text file formatted in XML will be great. If it's for multiple people you will have to use a database :)